# I get some “POST 404 (Not Found)” when I deploy the IPFS webui in production

Tags: ipfs

I followed all the guidelines to deploy property this helpful tool. When I make it in my local machine, all works fine. But when I try to deploy the same in a production server, it shows me some 404 errors that I don't understand why.

Here is my ipfs config file (the important lines):

```
"API": {
   "HTTPHeaders": {
   "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": [
      "true"
   ],
   "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": [
      "HEAD",
      "PUT",
      "GET",
      "POST"
   ],
   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": [
      "*"
   ]
}

"Addresses": {
   "API": "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001",
   "Gateway": "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8080",
   "Swarm": [
      "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/4001",
      "/ip6/::/tcp/4001"
   ]
}

"Gateway": {
   "HTTPHeaders": {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": [
         "X-Requested-With",
         "Range"
      ],
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": [
         "GET"
      ],
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": [
         "*"
      ]
   },
   "PathPrefixes": [],
   "RootRedirect": "",
   "Writable": false
},
```

Here is my nginx config file (the important lines, in order to set the proxypass):

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name gorillafirma.com;

   location /ipfsui {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001/webui/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }

   location /ipfs {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }
}
```

So, when I try to deploy the URL, http://208.68.36.4/ipfsui. I have getting this:

[image]
As you can see I am getting some 404 Errors that i don't understand. Taking into account that 208.68.36.4 is the IP for the gorillafirma.com domain